# Split image and name each half

Tags: linux, imagemagick-convert

I have images captured from a stereo camera which I want to split into left and right halves. If I do:

```
convert stereo0000.png -crop 50%x100% foo.png
```

I get `foo-0.png` and `foo-1.png`; how do I get `foo-left.png` and `foo-right.png`. Bonus points if I can do something like:

```
convert stereo*.png -crop 50%x100% foo-%d.png
```

And get `foo-0left.png`, `foo-0right.png`, `foo-1left.png`, `foo-1right.png`, etc. As it stands, that gives me `stereo0000.png` -> (`foo-0.png`, `foo-1.png`), `stereo0001.png` -> (`foo-2.png`, `foo-3.png`), which is not that useful.

Ideally the solution would be just a single call to `convert` for a wildcard input file pattern, as I can relatively easily write a shell script that renames the pair of files after a single call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RTFMing a little further, I found this acceptable two-liner:

```
convert stereo*.png -gravity East -crop 50%x100%+0+0 right%04d.png
convert stereo*.png -gravity West -crop 50%x100%+0+0 left%04d.png
```

This chops every image into left and right components

Answer (score 2):

Using two convert commands is twice as slow as each file has to be processed twice.

So, it is faster to use one convert and rename the resulting files:

```
$ convert stereo*.png -crop 50%x100% foo-%01d.png
$ mv foo-0.png foo-left.png
$ mv foo-1.png foo-right.png
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash,

```
for i in screen*.png; do convert "$i" -gravity East -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "right_$i"; done
for i in screen*.png; do convert "$i" -gravity West -crop 50%x100%+0+0 "left_$i"; done
```

worked for me.